# bytes requirements of teradata decimal

Tags: teradata

I am looking for a definite guide of the size requirements of decimals in TeraData. I think that 10 - 18 digits require 8 bytes meaning that the space requirements for decimal(10,2) and decimal(12,4) are the same. is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is IMO correct.

See here: http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Database_Management/B035_1094_109A/ch15.17.140.html